# Need help converting date in format 20120130 to Date data type oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you please help me in converting date from the format "20120101" to DATE format in Orcle Sql.

I looked at this [link](http://www.mandsconsulting.com/oracle-to_date-function-sql-syntax-examples) but it does not mention if the date format is custom..

EDIT: Is it possible to write any exclusion rule to the conversion function?

something like this "99999999" to "9999-12-31"? Is it possible?

Comment: your link explains it quite simply :) the dateformat is the format you specify, as in a custom value.

Comment: Your link specifies the formats within the "Sortable Table of Date Format Mask Options" section of that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT to_date('20120101','YYYYMMDD') FROM dual;
```

Comment: Can i add any exclusions to it like if the date is "99999999" set date to "9999-12-31"? Is it possible

Comment: Sure, just use a CASE statement to deal with possible values: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/case_when.html

Answer (score 2):

```
to_date('20120101','YYYYMMDD')
```

should be fine...

Answer (score 1):

You cans specify the format:

```
to_date('20120101', 'yyyymmdd')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string '20120101' that you want to convert into a date, assuming that the string contains a 4 digit year followed by a 2 digit month and a 2 digit day

```
to_date( '20120101', 'YYYYMMDD' )
```